# Spring Boot JPA Hibernate Parent/Child/Grandchild

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

When adding a new grandchild to the child of a parent, the object I'm adding seems to get replaced by a new object in the collection.  Same property values and it persists fine but the original object that I `new'd` does not contain the ID and has been removed from the collection.  Even after I've added the Child via setting `this` and then adding the Grandchild to the collection.

I need the object to get the ID so that I can map and return it back to the caller.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parents")
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @NotNull
    private long id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<ChildA> childrenA;
}



@Entity
@Table(name = "children_a")
public class ChildA {
    @NotNull
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Id
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", nullable = false)
    private Parent parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "childA", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<ChildB> childrenB;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public Parent getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Parent parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public void addChildB(ChildB childb) {
        childb.setChildA(this);
        childrenB.add(childB);
    }

    public Set<ChildB> getChildrenB() {
        return childrenB;
    }

    public void setChildrenB(Set<ChildB> childrenB) {
        this.childrenB = childrenB;
    }
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "children_b")
public class ChildB implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "child_a_id")
    private ChildA chiuldA;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public ChildA getChildA() {
        return childA;
    }

    public void setChildA(ChildA childA) {
        this.childA = childA;
    }

}
```

Comment: please share some code ...

Comment: Updated with code.  To be clear, when I add a ChildB via ChildA's addChildB method then everything saves.  But the object I add does not get the new ID, but a new object gets added to the collection and mine gets replaced.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into my child entities are being treated as Merges since the Parent's save via JPA repository is a merge.  This appears by design

Comment: I figured the same thing... the only solution I found is to persist new entities before adding them to the parent.